# Combine index and value of tenor to from a new tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a  tensor like `a = torch.tensor([1,2,0,1,2])`. I want to calculate a tensor `b` which has indices and values of tensor `a` such that:

`b = tensor([ [0,1], [1,2], [2,0], [3,1], [4,2] ])`.

Edit: `a[i] is >=  0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is:

```
b = torch.IntTensor(list(zip(range(0, list(a.size())[0], 1), a.numpy())))
```

Output:

```
tensor([[0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 0],
        [3, 1],
        [4, 2]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

Alternatively, you can also use `torch.cat()` as below:

```
a = torch.tensor([1,2,0,1,2])
indices = torch.arange(0, list(a.size())[0])
res = torch.cat([indices.view(-1, 1), a.view(-1, 1)], 1)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 0],
        [3, 1],
        [4, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = torch.tensor([1,2,0,1,2])
print(a)
i = torch.arange(a.size(0))
print(i)
r = torch.stack((i, a), dim=1)
print(r)
```

---

```
tensor([1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
tensor([[0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 0],
        [3, 1],
        [4, 2]])
```